# NancyFX Routes - multiple variable parameters

Tags: routes, url-routing, nancy

I have a list of urls which I have to use to render content to the browser.
I want to be able to dynamically deal with the request using nancyfx

the format of the urls are http;//mydomain.com/X/pathA/pathB/pathC/pathD
pathA, pathB, pathC and pathD are variable - meaning it could be anything (these are predefined but I don't want to physically add eacg on in)

How do I create the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Nancy capture segments are, by nature, greedy so a route like `/x/{stuff}` would capture your route and `{stuff}` would contain `pathA/pathB/pathC/pathD`